# Printer Preference Defaults - Duplex Printing

Tags: printing, network-printer

How are default printer preferences, such as the duplex printing option, determined when printing across a network?

I printed a multi-page pdf to a locally installed printer from one server on the network and got a single-sided print job.  I then printed the same multi-page pdf from another server on the network and got a two-sided print job.  Both jobs were printed on the same domain account.

Also, on the server that prints single-sided for print jobs run under the domain account, can I expect the same behaviour for print jobs run under the LocalSystem account?

EDIT:

Just want to provide an update to better define the problem. The print job is printing one sided when run from a regular domain account, but printing two sided when run from the Network Service account. The printer defaults for the printer are set to print one sided, which is desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether or not the clients connect directly to the printer or if they go through a print server. In the former case the default is set on each client. For the latter the default is set on the print server but can normally be over-ridden by the clients, which may also still have their own defaults. FWIW, the duplex printers I've personally come across all default to single sided out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Duplex and bin selection can be embedded within postscript (and other printer control languages). But usually if they're not provided, the printer will default to the options which have been configured on it.