# Way to force duplex printing on all Windows clients in domain

Tags: windows, group-policy, printing

I'm looking for a way to configure all of Windows clients in Active Directory domain so that they print all documents in **duplex mode**.

Serverfault has been similar questions:

- [How do i enforce duplex printing on Server
  2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/606653/how-do-i-enforce-duplex-printing-on-server-2012)
- [Printer Preference Defaults - Duplex
  Printing](https://serverfault.com/questions/230213/printer-preference-defaults-duplex-printing)

**But**:

- In my case, a lot of different printers (about 1000 at one site) and more customers.
- Not all printers connected via Print Servers (in some cases directly connected printers)
- Print job rendering always done on the client computers (otherwise will be long delays when printing)

What is tried:

- Сhanging the default print settings in the print server had no impact on the print settings from workstations where the printer has already been connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't tested it, but on Windows 8 and above you could create and push a powershell script that would look like that:

```
Get-Printer | Set-PrintConfiguration -DuplexingMode TwoSidedLongEdge
```

On Windows 7 Get-Printer is not defined, but you could bypass the problem with running a line like that in powershell to replace get-printer:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Printer | Select
Name,DriverName,PortName,Shared,ShareName | ft -auto
```

Comment: It's do not work for me: ` Get-Printer | Get-PrintConfiguration | ft -auto` returns `TwoSidedLongEdge` mode, but in "Print Propetries" window `OneSided` mode still selected, and printing goes to one side of the sheet. Of course the printer has a duplex and it works, if you select it manually.

Comment: @Slipeer after some tests, the powershell cmdlet seem to change the setting in 'printing default' (HKLM), not the one in printing 'preference' (HCU) if it was changed. It don't help much in your case. The only solution I can see now is a script that list all printer, remove the connection, and reconnect them after the duplex setting was changed

Comment: Can you provide registry path for this settings?

Comment: I did more experiments and found that the configuration worked for the locally connected network printer with the new driver, prepared for Vindovs 10. But did not work with the same printer connected via the Print Servers using older versions of the driver.